# How to learn designing performance test strategies and performance tuning?

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing, interview, learning

I have learned and implemented JMeter in my current project. Now I want to move to the next level and learn performance testing in depth. I gave an interview for a performance tester role and they asked me about designing performance test strategies, performance tuning and other topics that were Greek to me! How should I proceed and what skill-sets should I learn?

Answer (score 1):

Performance & Load testing is not a single discipline. Your strategy probably requires other roles like developers, devops, managers and or infrastructure admins. Similar roles are needed for the tuning and re-testing, maybe even just to create proof the applied changes after the first test really have a positive effect.

I mean, does the tester need to know how to change the performance of the database if it is a bottle-neck? Your probably need someone with DBA knowledge. How are you going to plan ahead, so you have the resources you need during the load-testing period.

Learning just the use of a single tool seems a bit underwhelming.

What are the next steps in getting more skills?:

- First [read some books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597619/best-practices-and-literature-for-web-application-load-testing%5C)
- Then read blogs and search for topics  and tools to research
- Experiment with topics you found and blog about it (best way to learn)